# Default Dict using a lot of memory Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a server with 32GB of memory and I find my script that it's consuming all that memory and even more because it's getting killed. Just want to ask what can I do on this scenario. I have a CSV file with 320,000 rows which I am iterating in Pandas. It has three columns called date, location and value. My goal is to store all location and values per date. So date is my key. I'm going to store it to s3 as a json file. My code in appending is like this

```
appends = defaultdict(list)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    appends[row["date"]].append(dict(
    location=row['location'],
        value=row['value'],
    ))
```

Then I will it to s3 like this

```
for key in appends.keys():
    try:
        append = appends[key]
        obj = s3.Object(bucket_storage, f"{key}/data.json")
        obj.put(Body=json.dumps(append, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
    except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

But this one is consuming all the memory. I've read somewhere that default dict can be memory consuming but I'm not sure what my other options are. I don'
t want to involve a database here as well.

Basically I need all the data to be mapped first in the dict before saving it to s3 but problem is I think it can't handle all the data or I am doing something wrong here. Thanks

Comment: can you correct the indentation?

Comment: @Nin17 it's corrected now. Sorry I did not noticed